# Python 3 - open file from console

Tags: python, file, path

I am trying to run the open() command on a file from the python console in a terminal rather than by running a script. For example, I would type the following to assign the file to the variable 'txt':

```
>>> txt = open(C:\\user\\documents\\python\\ex15_sample.txt)
```

Here is the output:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    txt = open(C:\\user\\documents\\python\\ex15_sample.txt)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I modify this command to successfully open the file at the listed path?

Comment: Uhm, use quotation marks?

Comment: You need to wrap your path with quotation : `txt = open("C:\\user\\documents\\python\\ex15_sample.txt")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote marks.

```
txt = open("C:\\user\\documents\\python\\ex15_sample.txt")
```